# How to mark a List or IEnumerable serializable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list to store in session in SqlServer mode.

```
[Serializable]
public class ModelStateSummary
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string[] ErrorMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Set the session

```
var list = new List<ModelStateSummary> {...};
Session["ModelStateSummaryModel"] = list;
```

But when I tried to retrieve the model from the session

```
var stateSummaries = Session["ModelStateSummaryModel"] as IEnumerable<ModelStateSummary>;
```

I got an error, saying,

> Exception type: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException Exception message: Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Web.Mvc.ModelState, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[myproject.ModelStateSummary, myproject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Have I done something wrong in saving the list into Session?

Comment: Be careful placing large objects into the session.

Answer (score 4):

When you put the object in the Session, it is serialized there. This also means that non-serializable objects cannot be stored there. Then when you get it out of the session, it gets deserialized. You can't deserialize to an interface. It must be a concrete class.

```
var stateSummaries = Session["ModelStateSummaryModel"] as List<ModelStateSummary>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `cast` like below.

```
var stateSummaries = (List<ModelStateSummary>)Session["ModelStateSummaryModel"];
```